# Push array into Object JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
 let x =[
    {
       name: x
       ratings:[
          {
             comment: 'something here',
            stars:'5',
          },

        ]
    },...]
```

In ratings i have to push more comments and stars:

```
 let newX = [
     {
          {
             comment: 'lalalalalalalal',
             stars:'4',
          },
          {
             comment: 'good',
             stars:'3',
          },
 },]
```

I am actually in a for loop, so I have x[i]; I have to push newX into x[i]. So I am doing x[i].ratings.push(newX) but I am getting 'push is not a function'

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: `x.ratings.push(newX)` will not work as you can see `x` is an array and not object. Instead, you can use `x[0].ratings.push(newX)`

Comment: ```.ratings[0]``` would be the object, and would therefor throw an error.

Comment: Keep in mind that with the above solution, you are pushing an array into an array. I imagine you don't want that to happen, so use concat. ```x[0].ratings = x[0].ratings.concat(newX);```

Comment: That `newX` is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `x` is an array, so `x.ratings` doesn't mean a lot. Do you want to add `newX` to `rating` inside the first element in `x`? If so, this is how you do it:

```
x[0].ratings.push(newX)
```

Comment: I am actually in a for loop, so I have x[i]; I have to push newX into x[i].
So I am doing x[i].ratings.push(newX)
but I am getting 'push is not a function'

Comment: Also please fix the `newX`. Is it supposed to be the same type as `x`, or is it just supposed to contain the ratings?